# Android inner locale return

Tags: android, localization

I have released inner localization in android app. Locale saved in preferences and get value when `onCreate()` called. But when I force stop app or reboot device locale restore for default(common device). Problem is reproduced only android 2.3, on android 4.0 localization is inner and was not changed.

```
String currentLocale = Localization.getLocaleFromPreferences(mPreferences);
Localization.setLocale(this, currentLocale, mPreferences);
```

The most intresting issue. In adb log after full initialization of app, locale is right. But when I click any view locale restore to device locale.

Comment: In your manifest do you have `android:configChanges="locale"` for the activities that you want it changed?